# Clever and simple explanation

Tags: combinatorics

Let $n,m,r\in \mathbb{Z}^{+}$ such that $n\geq 3$, $1\leq m\leq n-1$ and $2\leq r\leq n-1$.
I need a simple explanation. I do not want to think as a two variable of function the following expression. Maybe, the combinatorial aspect is what I need.
$$m^{n}-(m-1)^{n}-(m-1)^{n-1}-m^{n-r}$$

> - Why the values of it are positive for fixed $n$?
> - What is the maximum value of it for fixed $n$?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $x=m-1$, so the expression in terms of $x$ is
$$
(x+1)^n-x^n-x^{n-1}-(x+1)^{n-r}
$$
If you expand both $(x+1)^n$ and $(x+1)^{n-r}$ with the binomial theorem, and then collect like powers of $x$ together, the result is
$$
\left[1-1\right]\cdot x^0 + \left[n-(n-r)\right]\cdot x^1+\dots+ \left[\binom{n}k-\binom{n-r}k\right]x^k+\dots+\left[\binom{n}{n-2}-0\right]x^{n-2}
\\
+\left[\binom{n}{n-1}-1\right]x^{n-1}+\left[\binom{n}{n}-1\right]x^{n}
$$
The point is, this is a polynomial in $x$ where all coefficients are nonnegative integers. This is because $\binom{n}k-\binom{n-r}k\ge 0$, as it is easy to show the binomial coefficient is an increasing function of its upper index. It follows that substituting any nonnegative integer for $x$ gives a nonnegative output.

This also makes it clear that your expression, for fixed $r$, is maximized when $x$ is as large as possible, namely when $x=n-2$ and $m=n-1$. Furthermore, the coefficients increase as $r$ increases, so it is optimal to have $r$ be as large as possible. Therefore, the maximum value is
$$
(n-1)^n-(n-2)^n-(n-2)^{n-1}-(n-1)^{1}
$$

Comment: I’m so grateful. If we add $n^{n-r}$ in this expression, then I think $r$ is as small as possible for maximum value. Is it true?

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean by your comment, I think it would be better to ask a separate question.

Comment: I mean, let $n^{n-r}+m^{n}-(m-1)^{n}-(m-1)^{n-1}-m^{n-r}$. As you show, we find $m=n-1$ for the maximum value.  Then, we have  $n^{n-r}+ (n-1)^n-(n-2)^n-(n-2)^{n-1}-(n-1)^{n-r}$. Now we must find $r$ for maximum value. (Actually, it is easy to see $r=2$ by using your method.)

Comment: For your modified expression, yes, you want $r$ to be as small as possible.